# Japanese Language — Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion

**We want to congratulate and thank everyone that helped this site and community grow healthily into what they are today! おめでとうございます！**

If you can find your name among the top 72 users in the first two pages [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), we have a surprise for you! We want to send you a token of our appreciation for being among the most prolific users in this community! As such, we're sending you a little box, inside which you'll find:

**A T-SHIRT!**

[image: T-SHIRTS!!!!!!!]

**STICKERS!**

[image: STICKERS!!!!!!!]

I'll be reaching out to you later today with a link to a form: be sure to fill out the form as soon as you're able to do so! You'll have two weeks to do it, after which I'll close the form and take care of sending all of the swag your way! It should take from 6 to 8 weeks for the package to be delivered to you!

If you're not on the list, don't worry too much about it — we've got some extra swag stored we can send to you for events and such!

**Thanks to all of you for making this site great!**

Comment: Neat, thank you! I don't visit JLU nearly as much as I'd like to anymore, but I'll be back next year when I resume my studies in Japan :)

Comment: thanks a lot for the token.

Comment: I love swag! This is great!

Comment: It seems to me that the icon design shown in images is one version behind from current one on the site. I don't much care which, but is it intended?

Comment: Are things moving? I still have not received the token and I cannot wait to wear it

Comment: Still hasn't been shipped, @oldergod - I will update the Meta post once it has ;)

Comment: @JNat thank you!

Comment: Is the logo change causing problems?

Comment: I received my parcel today. Thanks!

Comment: Just arrived! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Got mine, thanks :)

Comment: The t-shirt was very soft. I love it :)

Answer (score 7):

As a user who won most of my points on questions rather than answers, I am the most grateful for this, and for all the help this site brings me.

Thanks to SE and to everyone making this site!

As noted by @broccoli_forest, the images above use a former version of the logo, though: the vertical stroke should go further down. This is important, so I hope you will end up using the right one. Otherwise the sticker looks great and reminds me of this art exhibition: http://www.2121designsight.jp/program/design_ah/.

The T-shirt has a シュール aspect to it and I am sure it will trigger interesting discussions :-)

[image]

Comment: Same. I was very surprised to receive an email, and I'm so thankful to everyone who helped me grow here.

Answer (score 6):

I was very happy to get this email. I have a few questions, though: what's your policy regarding information retention? What protocols are you using to guarantee that this data will be securely stored if you do so?

Cheers.

Comment: We currently store the information in a Google spreadsheet, and delete it once we have confirmation that everything's been sent out and that enough time for most (or preferably all) of the shipments have arrived. We're currently working on getting a better system implemented, that can take Google forms out of the picture as a middleman.

Answer (score 2):

I'm delighted to be chosen to receive a real world token for activities that I made in a virtual world :P

Just one question on the T-shirt sizing on https://districtclothing.com/fit-guide/. The T-shirt uses the Young Men's sizes or the Men's sizes? Is the cutting trim fit or relaxed fit? I'm XL on relaxed fit but XXL on trim fit ...

Sorry for such a boring question :P

Thanks again for the recognition.

Comment: It's supposed to be the young men's sizes. As for the fit... I'm not really sure :\